# JSHint fails with Timer.listOnTimeout error after generating Yeoman webapp

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

After generating a new Yeoman webapp with `yo webapp`, running `grunt` gives a JSHint error:

```
$ grunt
Running "newer:jshint" (newer) task

Running "newer:jshint:all" (newer) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

test/spec/test.js
  line 11  col 9  Expected '}' to have an indentation at 11 instead at 9.
  line 12  col 5  Expected '}' to have an indentation at 7 instead at 5.
  line 13  col 1  Expected '}' to have an indentation at 3 instead at 1.

✖ 3 problems

Warning: Task "jshint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.
Error: Task "jshint:all" failed.
    at Task.<anonymous> (/Users/ollieglass/code/ati/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:205:15)
    at null._onTimeout (/Users/ollieglass/code/ati/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:241:33)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-07-13 10:56:57 UTC)
loading tasks  1.1s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 91%
jshint:all     97ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 8%
Total 1.2s
```

What's causing this, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I'm having this same issue and can't find anyway to fix it. I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling node and npm and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by uninstalling then reinstalling Node, npm and Yeoman